# Does PriorityQueue call sorted every time get is called?

Tags: python, performance, sorting, priority-queue

The docs for [`queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) say:

> The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry is the one returned by `sorted(list(entries))[0]`).

Does that mean that every time I use the `get` method of a `PriorityQueue` that the elements are re-sorted? That would seem inefficient.

Comment: This is something common in the official documentation for python: they "explain" a function by saying "the result is equivalent to: <some simple but inefficient code>". Here it would be extremely inefficient to actually call `sorted(list(entries))[0]` every time you wanted to get the lowest-valued entry; what happens under the hood is much more efficient, but the result is the same.

Comment: @Stef True, but here it doesn't say anything like "is equivalent to".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That does not means that the elements are re-sorted every time when
> you use the get method.

The elements of a `PriorityQueue` are stored in a `binary heap data structure`, which allows for efficient retrieval of the smallest element when you call the method.

So when sorting is done in such a way that the lowest valued elements are always at the top of the heap. That's why you will get smallest value on first.

You can refer to [example and Explanation in deeply](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/heaps-and-priority-queues/)